# Is it possible to check in Inputtext the maxlength in the UnitTest spec file in Angular 6

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, angular6

i have a form with Inputs. One of them have a attribute maxlength = 5 (value).
The User can input only 5 character in this Input, not more.

Can i testing this in my spec.File?

I use Angular Version 6

```js
<input [maxLength]="value" type="text" formControlName="location"/>
```

i except the output in .spec green.

Comment: I need more information. Post the components code. html/css/ts or js/spec files.

Answer (score -1):

You can e.g. put a value > 5 chars inside this field and afterward you expect only the first 5 chars:

```
   it('location should accept only 5 character ', () => {
      form.get('country').patchValue({
        location: ('123456789')
      });
      form.get(‘country’).valueChanges.subscribe( value => {  
          expect(value).toBe('12345');
      }); 
   });
```

Comment: not working, i get Expected '123456789' to be '12345'

Comment: subscribe not working. Karma says "SPEC HAS NO EXPECTATIONS location should accept only 5 characters"

Answer (score -1):

not working.

```js
    it('location should accept only 5 character ', () => {
      form.get('country').patchValue({
        location: ('123456789')
      });
      expect(form.get('country').get('location').value).toBe('12345');
    });
```

The failure message i get: Expected '123456' to be '12345'

Comment: I've corrected the upper code to your testing model. You have to trigger valueChange.